# On Android, canvas is not being redrawn after onCompletion of playing a sound

Tags: java, android

I'm making a maze game for a class assignment, and one of the requirements is playing a sound at the start of the game and when the player reaches the exit.

I'm using onCompletionListener because when the player reaches the exit I have to wait until the sound has finished playing before playing the sound at the start of the next level, otherwise the app will hang.

However, now the screen is not being redrawn after the method createMaze() is called. If the player moves again, only then the canvas is redrawn and shows the newly created maze.

Here's what I expected the code to do:

1. Player reaches exit
2. Play Exit sound
3. After finishing playing the sound, create a new maze and draw it on the screen

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.labirinto;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;

public class GameView extends View implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    private enum Direction {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
    }

    private Vibrator vibrator;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor gyroscopeSensor;

    private static final int MAX_LEVELS = 3;
    private int currentLevel = 1;
    private String nextAction;

    private Cell[][] cells;
    private Cell player, exit;
    private static final int COLS = 7, ROWS = 10;
    private static final String
        ACTION_CREATE_MAZE = "ACTION_CREATE_MAZE",
        ACTION_END_GAME = "ACTION_END_GAME";


    private static final float WALL_THICKNESS = 4;
    private float cellSize, hMargin, vMargin;
    private Paint wallPaint, playerPaint, exitPaint;
    private Random random;

    MediaPlayer mp;

    public GameView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        wallPaint = new Paint();
        wallPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        wallPaint.setStrokeWidth(WALL_THICKNESS);

        playerPaint = new Paint();
        playerPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

        exitPaint = new Paint();
        exitPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        random = new Random();

        vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        gyroscopeSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

        createMaze();
    }

    private void createMaze() {
        Stack<Cell> stack = new Stack<>();
        Cell current, next;

        cells = new Cell[COLS][ROWS];

        for (int x = 0; x < COLS; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) {
                cells[x][y] = new Cell(x, y);
            }
        }

        player = cells[0][0];
        exit = cells[COLS - 1][ROWS - 1];

        current = cells[0][0];
        current.visited = true;

        do {
            next = getNeighbour(current);
            if (next != null) {
                removeWall(current, next);
                stack.push(current);
                current = next;
                current.visited = true;
            } else {
                current = stack.pop();
            }
        } while (!stack.empty());

        nextAction = "NOTHING";
        playSound("START");

    }

    private Cell getNeighbour(Cell cell) {
        ArrayList<Cell> neighbours = new ArrayList<>();

        //left neighbour
        if (cell.col > 0 && !cells[cell.col - 1][cell.row].visited) {
            neighbours.add(cells[cell.col - 1][cell.row]);
        }

        //right neighbour
        if (cell.col < (COLS - 1)  && !cells[cell.col + 1][cell.row].visited) {
            neighbours.add(cells[cell.col + 1][cell.row]);
        }

        //top neighbour
        if (cell.row > 0 && !cells[cell.col][cell.row - 1].visited) {
            neighbours.add(cells[cell.col][cell.row - 1]);
        }

        //bottom neighbour
        if (cell.row < (ROWS - 1) && !cells[cell.col][cell.row + 1].visited) {
            neighbours.add(cells[cell.col][cell.row + 1]);
        }

        if (neighbours.size() > 0 ) {
            int index = random.nextInt(neighbours.size());
            return neighbours.get(index);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void removeWall(Cell current, Cell next) {
        //current under next
        if (current.col == next.col && current.row == next.row + 1) {
            current.topWall = false;
            next.bottomWall = false;
        }

        //current above next
        if (current.col == next.col && current.row == next.row - 1) {
            current.bottomWall = false;
            next.topWall = false;
        }

        //current to the right of the next
        if (current.col == next.col + 1 && current.row == next.row) {
            current.leftWall = false;
            next.rightWall = false;
        }

        //current to the left of the next
        if (current.col == next.col - 1 && current.row == next.row) {
            current.rightWall = false;
            next.leftWall = false;
        }
    }

    public void drawCurrentLevelText(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        textPaint.setTextSize(48f);

        int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);

        canvas.drawText("Level " + currentLevel, xPos, 56, textPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        drawCurrentLevelText(canvas);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        if (width/height < COLS/ROWS) {
            cellSize = width/(COLS + 1) - 8;
        } else {
            cellSize = height/(ROWS + 1) - 8;
        }

        hMargin = (width - COLS*cellSize)/2;
        vMargin = (height - ROWS*cellSize)/2;

        canvas.translate(hMargin, vMargin);

        if (currentLevel == 2) {
            wallPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else if (currentLevel == 3) {
            wallPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < COLS; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) {
                if (cells[x][y].topWall) {
                    canvas.drawLine(x*cellSize, y*cellSize, (x + 1)*cellSize, y*cellSize, wallPaint);
                }

                if (cells[x][y].leftWall && !(x == 0 && y == 0)) {
                    canvas.drawLine(x*cellSize, y*cellSize, x*cellSize, (y+1)*cellSize, wallPaint);
                }

                if (cells[x][y].rightWall && !(x == COLS - 1 && y == ROWS - 1)) {
                    canvas.drawLine((x+1)*cellSize, y*cellSize, (x + 1)*cellSize, (y+1)*cellSize, wallPaint);
                }

                if (cells[x][y].bottomWall) {
                    canvas.drawLine(x*cellSize, (y+1)*cellSize, (x+1)*cellSize, (y+1)*cellSize, wallPaint);
                }
            }
        }

        float margin = cellSize/10;

        canvas.drawRect(
                player.col*cellSize+margin,
                player.row*cellSize+margin,
                (player.col + 1)*cellSize-margin,
                (player.row + 1)*cellSize-margin,
                playerPaint
        );

    }

    private void movePlayer(Direction direction) {
        switch (direction) {
            case UP:
                if (!player.topWall) {
                    player = cells[player.col][player.row - 1];
                } else {
                    vibrator.vibrate(400);
                }
                break;
            case DOWN:
                if (!player.bottomWall) {
                    player = cells[player.col][player.row + 1];
                } else {
                    vibrator.vibrate(400);
                }
                break;
            case LEFT:
                if (!(player.leftWall || player.col == 0)) {
                    player = cells[player.col - 1][player.row];
                } else {
                    vibrator.vibrate(400);
                }
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                if (!player.rightWall) {
                    player = cells[player.col + 1][player.row];
                } else {
                    vibrator.vibrate(400);
                }
                break;
        }

        checkExit();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void playSound(String type) {
        int resId;

        switch (type) {
            case "START":
                resId = R.raw.start;
                break;
            case "ERROR":
                resId = R.raw.retardado;
                break;
            case "EXIT":
                resId = R.raw.miseravel_genio;
                break;
            default:
                resId = 0;
                break;
        }

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), resId);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mp.release();

        switch (nextAction) {
            case ACTION_CREATE_MAZE:
                currentLevel++;
                createMaze();
                break;
            case ACTION_END_GAME:
                getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),com.example.labirinto.GameOver.class));
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Finished");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void checkExit() {
        if (player == exit) {
            if (currentLevel < MAX_LEVELS) {
                nextAction = ACTION_CREATE_MAZE;
            } else {
                nextAction = ACTION_END_GAME;
            }
            playSound("EXIT");
        }
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.sensor.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return true;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            float playerCenterX = hMargin + (player.col + 0.5f)*cellSize;
            float playerCenterY = vMargin + (player.row + 0.5f)*cellSize;

            float dx = x - playerCenterX;
            float dy = y - playerCenterY;

            float absDx = Math.abs(dx);
            float absDy = Math.abs(dy);

            if (absDx > cellSize || absDy > cellSize) {
                if (absDx > absDy) {
                    //move in x-direction
                    if (dx > 0) {
                        //move to the right
                        movePlayer(Direction.RIGHT);
                    } else {
                        //move to the left
                        movePlayer(Direction.LEFT);
                    }
                } else {
                    //move in y-direction
                    if (dy > 0) {
                        //move down
                        movePlayer(Direction.DOWN);
                    } else {
                        //move up
                        movePlayer(Direction.UP);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private class Cell {
        boolean topWall = true, leftWall = true, bottomWall = true, rightWall = true, visited = false;

        int col , row;

        public Cell(int col, int row) {
            this.col = col;
            this.row = row;
        }
    }
}
```

On the checkExit() method, if the player has reached the exit, I check if it's the final level to define the next action, and then I play the exit sound.

Then, on the playSound() method, I select the sound to play, set the listener and play the sound.

Finally, on the onCompletion() method, I release call the release() method on my MediaPlayer object, then I call the next action.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to find a solution by calling invalidate() inside the onCompletion() method. By doing this, the canvas is redrawn automatically.

I'm not sure if that was the best way to solve this, though.

```
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mp.release();

        switch (nextAction) {
            case ACTION_CREATE_MAZE:
                currentLevel++;
                createMaze();
                invalidate();
                break;
            case ACTION_END_GAME:
                getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),com.example.labirinto.GameOver.class));
                invalidate();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Finished");
                break;
        }
    }
```